# Is it really necessary to define devices when using data parallelism with Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, multi-gpu

I learned from its [original white paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.04467.pdf) that Tensorflow applies a greedy method for deciding on how to distribute operations among existing devices. However, the only multi-gpu example available on [Using multiple GPUs](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/using_gpu#using_multiple_gpus) suggests that Operations be gathered into "towers" and explicitly assigned to specific devices. Is it possible to simply define multiple copies of those towers and have Tensorflow to automagically assign them to different GPUs?